# R Leaflet - How to combine text and figure in popup?

Tags: html, css, r, leaflet, popup

I would like to combine text and a figure in a Leaflet Popup. I saw this on a website of Deutsche Bahn: [Multi-Object-Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoROZ.jpg)

Website:
[strecken.info](http://db-livemaps.hafas.de/bin/query.exe/dn?tpl=fullscreenmap&L=vs_baustellen&useZoomDependentPrio=false)

For me it would be sufficient to combine two of these 4 shown "windows" -> One text (paste0()) and one ggplot-figure). Is this possible in R?

Best regards and thank you very much :)

My Code so far:

```
ll_maps %>%
  addCircles(
    data = df_temp,
    lng = ~x_coord,
    lat = ~y_coord,
    weight = 1,
    radius = 1000,
    popup = ~lapply(leafpop::popupGraph(pic_list_temp, width = 500, height = 500), HTML),
    label = ~lapply(paste0("<br><b>Textline1</b> = ", tl1_object,
                    "<br><b>Textline2</b> = ", tl2_object), HTML),
    popupOptions = popupOptions(maxWidth = 500),
    labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "12px"),
    opacity = 1, 
    fillOpacity = 0.5,
    color = "red")
```

Now I would like to combine the label and the popup into one popup so to speak :)

Comment: Please share your code